# Minimum USB 2 control transfer latency

Tags: usb, latency

What is the minimum latency I can expect from a High Speed USB control transfer? I've written a little test program using libusb on OSX and WinUsb directly on Windows 10, and in both cases I get around 4 ms from submitting the transfer to receiving the result.

This seems high. (And I could have sworn I previously did a test on OSX and got sub-1 ms latency, but maybe I did something wrong...)

Does anyone know what the limitations are here? Surely there is a way to get at least close to 1 ms?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh I was being stupid. I had an inadvertent `printf()` over serial in my control transfer handler. With it removed I get a latency of around 120-160 µs on OSX via libusb and 240-330 µs on Windows 10 via WinUsb (in Parallels).